# Ajax call to a php file returning JS code in that file instead of executing it

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am making an ajax call to a php file, But I dont want it to return anything.

My php file has HTML content or rather a JS code, which needs to be executed over there itself. Please help me with this. I dont Know why this is happening

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        type   : "POST",
        url    : "<?php echo CALLBACKURL; ?>mobile_profile.php",
        data   : data,
        success: function(response){
        }
});
```

I am not giving any console.log but syill in the response its giving the whole of html 
code.

I need to execute that js code there itself and I dont want anything as response Or if we cant do this atleast can i run the JS code return nothing

Comment: The code you have provided seems to do everything you wanted.

Comment: And where, exactly, is "over there"?  Are you trying to persuade your server to run some javascript?

Comment: Why do you need ajax, when you just want to run some javascript? You need to get it somehow to the browser, so why not include it from the beginning?

Comment: Does it return *only* JavaScript code, or other stuff too?  Does it have `<script>` tags or not?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want your code to execute? In the browser or at the server?

If you do not want it to contact server and run there itself(inside browser), why are you using AJAX? You simply call a function which will do whatever you want.

on success what do you expect it to do? There is nothing inside the braces...

```
success: function(response){
}
```

Browsers cannot process php code. they can process only html and javascripts and some third party scripts with the help of add-ons.

Kindly be clear what you are expecting.

```
url: "<?php echo CALLBACKURL; ?>mobile_profile.php"
```

replace it with:

```
url: "mobile_profile.php"
```

and put those php tags inside that mobile_profile.php, if required.

If you wish, you can pass parameters to that php file by suffixing your? and a querystring so that the called php file understands what to do.

I think this helps.